# Notation for function updated at input

Tags: functions, notation

Given a function $f \colon A \to B$, input $\hat{a} \in A$, and output $\hat{b} \in B$, what are standard/common/possible notations for $f' \colon A \to B$ which is $f$ except for mapping $\hat{a}$ to $\hat{b}$?

$$
f'(a) = \begin{cases}
  \hat{b} & \text{ if } a = \hat{a} \\
  f(a) & \text{ if } a \neq \hat{a}
\end{cases}
$$

---

Over the years, I think I have seen these options around, but not sure if they are standard? Probably there is a better option?

1. $f[\hat{a} \mapsto \hat{b}]$
2. $f \oplus \hat{a} \mapsto \hat{b}$
3. $f \cup \{a \mapsto b\}$

Comment: What's wrong with writing $f'(a)=\begin{cases}\hat{b},&a=\hat{a},\\f(a),&a\neq\hat{a}\end{cases}$ like you initially did?

Comment: I need this in many places, even in some subscripts, so I need a concise notation. Preferably a standard one.

Comment: I don't think there is a more standard one than that, so if you use it a lot, just introduce your own notation, as long as you're clear

Comment: $f'(a)=f(a)+(\hat{b}-f(a))g(a-\hat{a})$, where $g(x)=1$ for $x=0$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Of all the notations you propose the most clear and understandable seems to be the one with the big curly left bracket and two cases inside it. If you really need a shorthand then define your own, state it clearly, and then use it. There is no standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I have seen a standard way of doing this, but if we are to invent a way, it should preferably be clear from it which function has precedence. This could be a suggestion:
$$
f_{[\hat{a}\ \mapsto\ \hat{b}]}
$$
or maybe better something like:
$$
f\triangleleft[\hat{a}\ \mapsto\ \hat{b}]
$$
in this way one could do a series of functions with first choice, second choice etc. and combine with restricting to smaller domains if necessary:
$$
f\triangleleft g|_{A}\triangleleft h|_{B}
$$
which means:

> Use $h$ if input is in $B$, otherwise use $g$ if input is in $A$, lastly use $f$.

---

The choice of symbol $\triangleleft$ is only because we want some direction to be clear from the notation, so you could use either kind of directed notation that you prefer. Then define such notation early on and use it throughout.